# Salesforce.com - invalid quantity change on opportunity line item

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

This error has been plaguing me for two weeks now.  I'm new to Apex so it might be easy.

I have a trigger on After Opportunity Update.

```
trigger triggerOpportunityCloseInstallDateChange on Opportunity (after update) 
{ 
    if(!Validator_cls.IsOpportunityScheduleUpdated())
    {
        Validator_cls.SetOpportunityScheduleUpdatedDone();
        OpportunitySchedule.BuildScheduleAndUpdateDates(trigger.new, true);
    }
}
```

I have that wrapper around it to make sure it only gets called once per update.

When that trigger fires, it is supposed to update the schedule date on the line items, that in-turn updates the line items schedule.

```
public static void BuildScheduleAndUpdateDates(List<Opportunity> OpportunityList, Boolean DoUpdateItems) 
{
    system.debug('***********OpportunitySchedule             : BuildScheduleAndUpdateDates HIT');
    Map<String, Opportunity> OppMap =  new Map<String, Opportunity>();
    List<OpportunityLineItem> ItemsToUpdate = new List<OpportunityLineItem>(); 
    List<String> IdList = new List<String>();

    for (Integer i = 0; i < OpportunityList.size(); i++)
    {
        IdList.add(OpportunityList[i].Id);
        OppMap.put(OpportunityList[i].Id, OpportunityList[i]);
    }

    List<OpportunityLineItem> lineItems = [Select o.Id, (Select OpportunityLineItemId From OpportunityLineItemSchedules), o.Opportunity.Id, o.Systems_Add_On__c, o.ServiceDate, o.Product_Family__c, o.Schedule_Length__c , o.Monthly_Quantity__c, o.Monthly_Amount__c, o.Quantity
                                            From OpportunityLineItem o
                                            where o.Opportunity.Id in:IdList];

        for (OpportunityLineItem item : lineItems)
        {   
            Opportunity opp_new = OppMap.get(item.Opportunity.Id);

            Boolean hasSchedule = OpportunityProductLineItems.DoesLineItemHaveSchedule(item.Id);

            if (opp_new.Term_Conversion__c != null)
            {   
                item.ServiceDate = opp_new.CloseDate;
            }
            else
            {
                if(item.Product_Family__c == 'Systems')
                {
                    if(item.Systems_Add_On__c == true)
                    {
                        item.ServiceDate = opp_new.Install_Date__c;
                        system.debug('***********BuildScheduleAndUpdateDates     : Systems With Systems Add On ' + item.ServiceDate);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        item.ServiceDate = opp_new.Install_Date__c.addDays(30); 
                        system.debug('***********BuildScheduleAndUpdateDates     : Systems With NO Systems Add On ' + item.ServiceDate);
                    }
                }
                else if(hasSchedule)
                {
                    item.ServiceDate = opp_new.Install_Date__c.addDays(30); 
                    system.debug('***********BuildScheduleAndUpdateDates     : Has Schedule ' + item.ServiceDate);
                }
                else
                {
                    item.ServiceDate = opp_new.Install_Date__c;
                    system.debug('***********BuildScheduleAndUpdateDates     : No Schedule ' + item.ServiceDate);
                }
            }

            //item.Quantity = 1;
            ItemsToUpdate.add(item);
            if(hasSchedule && !DoUpdateItems)
            {
                ProcessSchedule(item);
            }
        } 

    if(DoUpdateItems)
    {
        update ItemsToUpdate;
    }    
    upsert schedulesToUpsert;

}
```

When I update an opportunity, I get this error:

```
Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger triggerOpportunityCloseInstallDateChange caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: triggerOpportunityCloseInstallDateChange: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00kV0000002cHhTIAU; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception: unknown (invalid quantity change on opportunity line item): [unknown]: Class.OpportunitySchedule.BuildScheduleAndUpdateDates: line 68, column 1
```

That error corresponds to this line

```
update ItemsToUpdate;
```

As you can see above, I'm not changing the quantity on that line item.  I'm so confused.  If I comment out that line, everything works fine (the schedule is built and updated).

I've even put in `item.Quantity = 1;` to see if I could manually set the quantity.

**What does this error mean, and how do I get past it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is typically attributed to some type of special fields that salesforce needs to keep synchronized on the back end.  For example, that error will come up if you add a Line Item with a different Pricebook than the one set for the Opportunity.

In this instance, it is probably due to either some external force changing the quantity or possibly Schedule Records relying on the Line Item's quantity being a specific value.

For the external force changing the quantity, I would try putting a debug statement before and after your call to `ProcessSchedule(item)`.  Since SObjects are passed to functions [by reference](http://th3silverlining.com/2009/08/03/apex-lists-of-sobjects-by-value-or-reference/), it is possible that that function is modifying `item` without you realizing it.

It's hard to say exactly what the issue might be without knowing some of the other code, but hopefully this will help get you in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
OppMap.put(OpportunityList[i].Id, OpportunityList[i].clone(true, true));
```

The first "true" in the clone call retains the Ids of your sObjects and the second instructs clone to perform a deep copy, breaking the by reference problem.

[Edit]

Re-reading your post I realized that this might not solve your problem - sorry! But the deep clone trick does help with the by reference problem. Good luck.